# Excel: Is there an Excel function/query or using Python where I can find number of matching characters or percentage of match between two cells?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, excel-formula

I am looking for a way to separate multiple codes/text and then parse them for matches between them.
For example:

```
 A1 = 2024 / 2033 / 2035                    B1 = 2024 / 2033 / 2035  C1= 3
 A2 = 1311 / 2299 / 2399 / 2813 / 2821      B2 = 6733                C2 = 0
 A3 = 1221 / 1222 / 1241                    B3 = 1222 / 1221         C3 = 2
```

The function should separate the values in cell A1 by '/' and then check if any of them occur in Cell B1. The number of occurrences should be given in Cell C1. So since A1 had 3 codes of text which occurred in B1, C1 gives a value of 3.

The text will be of 4 characters length only.

[example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwMpK.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO is not a code "factory" please show, what you tried, what you expect and what actually happened. Tip: Have a look at [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split),  [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) and [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-membership-identity-operators-not-not/)

Comment: hey! I tried a bunch of excel functions with split to text columns and countifs option. Which returned #value errors. Haven't tried Python yet. Thanks for the tips. This is my first time asking a question on SO, so didn't know the format. Will keep in mind next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use:

```
print(df)

                                  A                   B 
0                2024 / 2033 / 2035  2024 / 2033 / 2035 
1  1311 / 2299 / 2399 / 2813 / 2821                6733 
2                1221 / 1222 / 1241         1222 / 1221
```

---

```
df['count duplicated']=df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.str.replace(' ','').str.split('/').sum()).duplicated().sum(),axis=1)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
                                  A                   B  count duplicated
0                2024 / 2033 / 2035  2024 / 2033 / 2035                 3
1  1311 / 2299 / 2399 / 2813 / 2821                6733                 0
2                1221 / 1222 / 1241         1222 / 1221                 2
```

Comment: Hey! thanks for this! Do I need to add any other lines to this code other than reading the data into the df? Because the above two lines did not work. Gave me a "Series has no split attribute error". :/

Comment: sorry! check now I forgot .str before split

Comment: Getting a TypeError: **TypeError: ("unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'", 'occurred at index 2').**

        Here's the code I'm using for your reference: 
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
print(df.head())
print(df)
df['count duplicated']=df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.str.replace(' ','').str.split('/').sum()).duplicated().sum(),axis=1)
print(df)

Comment: any luck in debugging it? I've gone through all answers on SO for this. No idea what's the issue.

Comment: try: `df['count duplicated']=df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.astype(str).str.replace(' ','').str.split('/').sum()).duplicated().sum(),axis=1)`

Comment: THANKS A TON! You really helped me out here. Thank you. :)